# how do I fetch data that are exist in another collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have two collections, first is **sagment**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6436b5173f502ed769062ae3"),
    "app_id" : "5d1554b5d2a57d5cda075922",
    "created_on" : ISODate("2023-04-12T13:41:43.501+0000"),
    "name" : "ABCD",
    "type" : "dynamic"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("8436b513f502ed769062148"),
    "app_id" : "5d1554b5d2a57d5cda075922",
    "created_on" : ISODate("2023-04-12T13:41:43.501+0000"),
    "name" : "XYZ",
    "type" : "dynamic"
}
```

second is **auto**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6440e09511590b6c360f0962"),
    "created_on" : ISODate("2023-04-20T06:49:57.000+0000"),
    "auto_name" : "Folder",
    "trigger" : "added_to_segments",
    "trigger_value" : [
        "6436b5173f502ed769062ae3"
    ]
}
```

i need to fetch **sagment** that are only exist in **auto** collection **trigger_value**

need output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6436b5173f502ed769062ae3"),
    "app_id" : "5d1554b5d2a57d5cda075922",
    "created_on" : ISODate("2023-04-12T13:41:43.501+0000"),
    "name" : "ABCD",
    "type" : "dynamic"
}
```

I have tried

```
$this->mongo_db->aggregate(
    'sagment',
    [
        ['$match' => ['app_id' => $app_id]],
        ['$sort' => ['created_on' => -1]],
        ['$skip' => (int)$offset],
        ['$limit' => $limit],
        ['$lookup' => [
            'from' => 'auto',
            'localField' => 'trigger_value',
            'foreignField' => '_id',
            'as' => 'pip'
        ]]
    ]
);
```

I am getting all sagment data. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing, perform lookup first from segment to auto collection, then filter the docs having no matched auto documents. Like this:

```
db.segment.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "auto",
      "let": {
        id: "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$$id",
                {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": "$trigger_value",
                    "in": {
                      "$toObjectId": "$$this"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "auto_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      auto_docs: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      auto_docs: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nMEetMeKvxf)